# Preserve X between Ssh -X sessions

Tags: ssh, xserver, tmux

I have a powerful Ubuntu workstation with EDA tools installed, and several Windows-10 laptops on my network.

Laptop Windows users have [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) installed, as an X-server, ssh and sftp clients. They normally ssh, start some GUI EDA tools that run for hours, then copy back stuff to windows.

If the ssh connection is disrupted the GUI tools are killed. I managed to solve non-GUI commands using "tmux". I googled about an X-based tmux like, but failed to replicate others experiences. (setting $DISPLAY with tmux, or using Xpra)
When I re-attach, I always find the GUI tool with an error like:

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "localhost:13.0"
  after 225 requests (91 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

What am I missing? Is it related to Windows/MobaXterm?

Comment: See http://xpra.org and the arch wiki for a how to attach detach and reattach https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xpra

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out this wiki. I cannot find an Xpra version without memory leaks. I tried 0.14, 0.15 and 2.3.2-r19729. Their change logs are full with leak fixes, but seems many are still hidden. @Panther do you know a stable version? Alternative?

Comment: My only other suggestion would be a VNC server.

Comment: For multiple users? I don't think it's possible.

Comment: What do you mean by multiple users? It depends one the vnc server, some are independent sessions, some are shared.